# How to read integer values from text file

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Reading integers from a file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array)

I want to read integer values from a text file say contactids.txt. in the file i have values like

```
12345
3456778
234234234
34234324234
```

i Want to read them from a text file...please help

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might want to do something like this (if you're using java 5 and more)

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("tall.txt"));
int [] tall = new int [100];
int i = 0;
while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
     tall[i++] = scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Via [Julian Grenier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23051/julien-grenier) from [Reading Integers From A File In An Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array/304061#304061)

Comment: You are using the same answer that is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array/304061#304061)

Comment: I've added the required citations to your answer. Please make sure to do that in the future.

Comment: File file = new File("tall.txt"); 
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
integers.add(scanner.nextInt());
} else {
scanner.next();
}
}
System.out.println(integers);

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and its [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method.

Scanner also has [`nextLong()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong%28%29) for larger integers, if needed.

Comment: +1 I would use `nextLong()` as `34234324234` is too large for an `int`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:-

```
File file = new File("contactids.txt");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
while(scanner.hasNextLong())
{
  // Read values here like long input = scanner.nextLong();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How large are the values? Java 6 has Scanner class that can read anything from int (32 bit), long (64-bit) to BigInteger (arbitrary big integer).

For Java 5 or 4, Scanner is there, but no support for BigInteger. You have to read line by line (with readLine of Scanner class) and create BigInteger object from the String.

Answer (score 1):

use **FileInputStream**'s **readLine()** method to read and parse the returned String to int using **Integer.parseInt()** method.

Comment: I'd not found `readLine()` in `FileInputStrem`

Comment: what @MohammadFaisal said

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D mohammad asked the right question, the `readline()` method  is not present in `FileInputStream` but it is in  `BufferedReader`. Moreover, `FileInputStrem.read() method returns only types `int char byte`

Answer (score 1):

I would use nearly the same way but with list as buffer for read integers:

```
static Object[] readFile(String fileName) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    List<Integer> tall = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        tall.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }

    return tall.toArray();
}
```