# Bubble Sort .txt file containing integers in java

Tags: java, sorting

I want to be able to bubble sort a txt file that contains scores. I have been able to sort alphabets but not integers. I done have an idea on how to go about it. Any solution or input would be highly appreciated. Here is the bubble sort code i have already.

```
public static void bubbleSort(int array[]) {
        boolean swapped = true;
        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                    swapped = true;
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Comment: How doesn't it really work? It's working fine for me. Are you sure?

Comment: Is your problem reading integer values instead of sorting them? Did you have any exception?

Comment: I want actually read a txt file that contains integers and then sort using bubble sort .... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is no need for you to use Bubble Sort specifically, use the `Arrays.sort()` method for sorting the array.

It goes like this `Arrays.sort(array);`

Comment: This is not the answer which is expected, he wants bubble sort then you must answer the bubble sort algo

Comment: Specifically bubble sort. I want to read a txt file that contains integers and sort it using bubble sort.

Comment: In that case, your Bubble Sort implementation works just fine for me. Are you sure the problem is not reading the integers from the file?

Comment: [How to read integers from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752484/how-to-read-integer-values-from-text-file)