# Scanner issue with "hasNextInt()"

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have a file that has a different integer on each line. for example:

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

I am trying to write a program to run through each int, and put that int into an array. So far, my code is:

```
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(args[0]);

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
      lines = 0;
      while (reader.readLine() != null) lines++;
      reader.close();

      intArray = new int[lines];

      int counter = 0;
      while(sc.hasNextInt()) {
        intArray[counter] =sc.nextInt();
        counter++;
      }
```

My program creates the array with the right number of indices, but it is never going into the while loop for the scanner. I have no idea why this is, as it looks like I have the same code according to this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array).

Answer (score 3):

Unless your file path is space separated numbers, you won't get any numbers. The `Scanner` [was scanning the file path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) (as a `String`), not the file.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(args[0]));
```

And FYI, it would be more clear if you used a `List` rather than reading the file twice.

Comment: That was the trick, it was looking at the string not the file. Perfect!