# Turning a TextIO file into a vector (array) which it then returns

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, type-conversion

I'm trying to write a program for homework that opens a file that is given by the string and reads a series of comma separated integer values into an array, which it then returns.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

...

```
int[] readVector(String filename) throws IOException {
    File f = new File(filename);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);

    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
    pw.println("");
    pw.close();

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while (true) {
        String s = bfr.readLine();
        if (s == null) {
            break;
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    bfr.close();;

    return NOIDEA;
}
```

Consider this...

```
Matrix m = new Matrix();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.readVector("vector.txt"))); // print "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

Comment: ......... and your specific question is?

Comment: Oh sorry, I want to know how to convert a text file into a vector.  Not sure how that can be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file contents to an array, then convert using this:

```
Vector<Integer> returnVec = new Vector(Arrays.asList(YOUR_ARRAY));
```

If you're having trouble **also** reading the text file into an array then look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array).

Comment: My only problem with this is that the return statement needs to be an int array.

Comment: Perfect. In that case just return the original array. So here's the flow to give you an idea: FIrst, read all ints from file into an array. If that's all you need to do then check the link in my answer. If you then need to convert it to a vector, use the syntax I provided. When you are finished with any operation, just return the original integer array.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description,
your implementation contains a lot of stuff it doesn't really need,
for example `FileOutputStream` and `PrintWriter`.
And if the values are on a single line,
then it's enough to process a single line,
which is easy enough to do with a `Scanner`.

This should do it:

```
int[] readVector(String filename) throws IOException {
    return Arrays.stream(new Scanner(new File(filename)).nextLine().split(","))
           .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
}
```