# Reading from a file in java and save the int numbers from the txt in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am really new in java and I am trying to improve by exercising at home. I have this problem with my program, I can't save the int numbers from the txt file that I am reading in an array so I can work on it.

[My new code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Pnof.png)

Comment: Try to format your code properly, there is plenty of empty or strangely placed "{}" blocks.

Comment: the for block {} is not correct

Comment: @Joe K. , can you please edit the question and add the code as text. External images can be 'lost' :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Reading integers from a file into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array)

Comment: I am not in that level to completely understand what null and the other codes i saw are ..I just want to know how to save the numbers of an txt.file in an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use BufferReader to read the txt

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/input.txt"));
```

Then all you need to do is iterate through using br.readLine() and assign it to an array as below:

```
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    array[i]= Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
                    i++;
                }


            for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                System.out.println(array[j]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is out-of-scope in the print statement.

It will only be available in the for block. Whereas your print statement is outside the for loop.

It should be surrounded by a `{}` block to make it available for more than 1 statement.

```
for(int i =0; i < array.length; i++){

array[i] = in.nextInt();

System.out.println(array[i]);}
```

Comment: I did i global,it compiles but i get run time error :    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: You are assigning the first number to `num` (length of the array), so your first line in .txt should be the number of  the subsequent `int`'s.

Comment: @cylon True, But I didn't find a statement which calls `array[1]`, that's the reason I asked him to edit for the new code.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

```
 int []array=new int[num];
```

which creates an array of length 1, since you do

```
num = in.nextInt();
```

You could for example use a `List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>()` then you can add your ints to the list in your loop.

Comment: @JoeK. You're mixing while loop with for loop. Which isn't necessary in this case. Use one loop.