# how to read Integer from a text file in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to read a file which contains integer values in java and i have found the following answer for this:

[Java: Reading integers from a file into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303913/java-reading-integers-from-a-file-into-an-array)

But my code stuck in infinite loop.

My code is :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/home/lalit/Desktop/Project/key_x.txt"));
        //Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("/home/lalit/Desktop/Project/key_y.txt"));

           int i = 0,count=0;
           while(scanner.hasNextInt())
           {
                System.out.println("This is count "+count);
               count++;
           }
```

The above code goes in infinite loop.

My text file contains :

317

40

280

10

318

24

456

126

4

129

404

468

287

275

165

I got one more problem in this, when i try to store the elements in int array then it throws exception ;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Hybrid.Image.main(Image.java:503)
```

my code of storing array elements is :

```
  int tall[] =new int[count];
   int tall1[] =new int[count];
   while(scanner.hasNextInt())
   {
        int k=scanner.nextInt();
        tall[i] =k;
        System.out.println(tall[i]);
        i++;
   }
```

Comment: You never fetch the value in the loop. You have to call `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 4):

The loop never ends because the condition never changes.  You're only checking if the scanner *has* a "next `int`", you never actually read that `int`.  So it's always ready to read the first `int` in the file.

If you don't care what that `int` is and just want to read it from the scanner, you can do that and simply ignore the value:

```
while(scanner.hasNextInt())
{
    scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println("This is count "+count);
    count++;
}
```

Alternatively, if you *do* want to actually do something with that `int`, it'll be in the return value of `scanner.nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code as shown below because you are never fetching the value.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("/home/lalit/Desktop/Project/key_x.txt"));
        //Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(new File("/home/lalit/Desktop/Project/key_y.txt"));

           int i = 0,count=0;
           while(scanner.hasNextInt())
           {
                scanner.nextInt()
                System.out.println("This is count "+count);
               count++;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating a `Scanner` it has an inner state. This state can be changed when you're getting the data from it using `scanner.nextXXX()` API.

`scanner.hasNextInt()` **doesn't change the state**. Only checks it. While `scanner.nextInt()` does change its state, and then in the next time you're calling it, it will fetch the next piece of data.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to move the cursor.

A scanner works by reading an input stream. You can imagine getting the entire file in one long string and then a cursor in the start of it. Then when you call .hasNextInt() you ask the scanner if there is an integer in front of the cursor at the current position. If there is it will return true but won't actually move the cursor. The cursor will only move when you call nextInt(). And scanner.nextInt() will return an integer as well.